# Android Simulator unable to access the photo library with PhoneGap

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova

Is it possible to use this function in PhoneGap:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoLoadSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
```

The onFail always gets called because it can't access the camera.  I understand the simulator doesn't have a camera, but I'd like to think it would still be possible to access the photo library.

I have set the SD card to 20GB as well already.

Anyone able to get this working?

Edit:

I receive the following errors:

```
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ImageGallery}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:204)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2338)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2545)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:219)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1786)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at com.android.camera.ImageGallery.onCreate(ImageGallery.java:113)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
10-20 16:46:53.418: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(632):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
```

Also as a note, this works ok:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoLoadSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
```

But not when the sourceType is set...

Comment: is camera attribute present in the AVD?

Comment: see my edit, not specifying the sourceType loads the camera...

Comment: @endyourif its not your fault http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15104